# I have one key left for an old Mortise lock, where can I find blanks?

Tags: doors, lock

I have one key left for 2 Mortise locks in my house.  I would like to find blanks to have spares cut.  Where is the best place to find or order blanks for such locks.  It is not a skeleton key.  It looks like a standard c key but about 1/8" longer possibly a 8 or 9 pin cylinder.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If a locksmith can't help you, then perhaps posting a picture of the key here would help.

Comment: It would also help provide more info if you provide any branding data of the lock housing.  And add photos of the lock pulled from door.